# Consumer RabbitMQ symfony2 not work

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

In the Symfony 2.7 application I'm developing I need to consume about RabbitMQ data.
I install RabbitMQBundle and good, but when I try to consume I get the following error

```
 [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPProtocolChannelException]
 ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'options' in vhost '/' refused for user 'user'
```

config.yml:

```
 old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
      default:
        host:     'my-url'
        port:     5672
        user:     'user'
        password: 'pass'
        vhost:    '/'
        lazy:     false
        connection_timeout: 3
        read_write_timeout: 3

        # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
        keepalive: false

        # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
        heartbeat: 0
  consumers:
    read_node:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: { name: 'options', type: direct}
        queue_options:    { name: 'options' }
        callback:         process_node
```

services.yml:

```
 services:
     process_node:
        class: AppBundle\Consumer\RabbitConsumer
```

RabbitConsumer.php

```
  namespace AppBundle\Consumer;

 use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
 use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

 class RabbitConsumer implements ConsumerInterface{


    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

console command:

```
  php ./app/console rabbitmq:consumer read_node
```

I made a pure php script and working properly
I hope someone can help me

Comment: You are getting the error "ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'options' in vhost '/' refused for user 'user'" so try to see what the user 'user' can't access the 'options' exchange on that vhost

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the user and password to 'guest' and 'guest' respectvely, if you didnt change the default user settings of rabbitmq.

Otherwise you will need to create a new user in rabbitmq called 'user' and set the password to 'pass', for the code that you pasted above to work. But I suggest you change it to something sensible.

change user:

```
rabbitmqctl change_password tonyg newpass
```

add user:

```
add_user {username} {password}`
```

[More info on the manual page of rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)